# Xcode 7.1 Simple app just shows white screen in sim

Tags: xcode

I created a Single View App. Nothing bunch, When I run it I get a white blank screen in the simulator. Under Info, Main Interface is set to 'Main', I've tried setting it to "LaunchScreen" or "Main.Storyboard"
Still blank white screen.
Ideas?

Comment: have you changed anything in the storyboard (like added a label or changed the color of a view)?  Also, delete the app from the simulator and re-build & re-install it, you may see your storyboard changes then.

Comment: I have the same issue following a tutorial. I also found another post related to this. This is odd, seem like it happens after 7.1 update?